# iOS Geofencing didDetermineState forRegion is CLRegionStateInside for all regions

Tags: ios, geofencing

I'll try to express this question with only relevant details.

I'm working on some geofencing for an app that claims that the device is inside several regions at once.
I used to have the geofencing work like a charm, but then had to add some extra code, that really shouldn't interfere with this.

I'm doing some testing in the simulator and in real life.
As I let it monitor regions based on the latest location and stopped receiving didEnter/ExitRegion events I decided to requestState forRegion when a region starts being monitored. 
Like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"didStartMonitoringForRegion: %@" ,region.identifier);
    [manager requestStateForRegion:region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    switch (state) {
        case CLRegionStateUnknown:
            [self.delegate writeToConsole:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CLRegionStateUnknown %@", region.identifier ]];
            break;
        case CLRegionStateOutside:
            [self.delegate writeToConsole:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CLRegionStateOutside %@", region.identifier ]];
            break;
        case CLRegionStateInside:
            [self.delegate writeToConsole:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CLRegionStateInside %@", region.identifier ]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This gives me CLRegionStateInside for every single one. How is that possible? None of these regions are on top of each other. I draw the regions as circles (they're CLCircularRegions) on a mapview.

On the simulator I can simulate locations on when I "move" far away from my regions I get didExitRegion on every one. And when I go back near them I'll receive didEnterRegion on all currently monitored regions. It's basically like the regions are huge and overlapping. But they're not. Furthermore, it used to work just fine with getting didEnter/ExitRegion.

I tried a lot of things including removing the new code, and it still behaves this way.

Why would it think I'm in several regions at once?

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

You better try to check in Real device then simulator. didEnter/ExitRegion Has got 100 meters accuracy errors

Comment: I test both real device and simulator. Real device typically does best. I'm aware of the level of accuracy. The regions I use in my test are further away from each other than that. Most of them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out that WiFi being on GREATLY affects accuracy of region monitoring. I had it turned off. That explains why I felt my code worked as randomly as the wind blows. Well I hope that was it. I'm getting consistent tests on the simulator. I hope a real test on the ride home will prove me right.